# How To navigate from createMaterialTopTabNavigatorto other screen - React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have some issue when navigating from top Tabnavigator to other screens 
so my app navigation is

> My Orders Screen from Drawer => Top TabNavigatore (Accepted/Completed) => **Order Details**

In Route.js 
I put every single navigation I want like Drawer - Auth navigation and so on, and I put a StackNavigator contain the Orders Screen like this:

```
const OrdersStack = createStackNavigator({
  Orders: {
    screen: Orders,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerLeft: (
        // <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
        >
          <Icon
            name="ios-menu"
            size={40}
            style={{ margin: 10 }}
            color="#2F98AE"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
      headerRight: <View />,
      title: "My Orders",
      headerTintColor: "#2F98AE",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#2F98AE",
        // textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25
        // justifyContent: "center"
      }
    })
  }
});
```

In the Orders.js I put these:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import NavTabs from "../screens/NavTabs";
import NavOrderDetails from "../screens/NavOrderDetails";

// create a component
export default class Orders extends Component {
  render() {
    return <MyOrdersScreen />;
  }
}

export const root = createStackNavigator({
  NavTabs: NavTabs,
  NavOrderDetails: NavOrderDetails
});

const MyOrdersScreen = createAppContainer(root);
```

As I mentioned in Orders.js it Contains Tabs and Order Details

In Tabs, I'm creating a **createMaterialTopTabNavigator**

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import AcceptedOrders from "../screens/AcceptedOrders";
import CompletedOrders from "../screens/CompletedOrders";

const MainTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Accepted: { screen: AcceptedOrders },
    Completed: { screen: CompletedOrders }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#fff",
      inactiveTintColor: "#ddd",
      tabStyle: {
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#fcc11e"
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#2F98AE"
      }
    }
  }
);
export default MainTabs;
```

and another screen is OrderDeatils.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import OrderDetails from "../screens/OrderDetails";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
const OrderDetailsStack = createStackNavigator({
  OrderDetails: {
    screen: OrderDetails,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Order Details",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#2F98AE",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#2F98AE",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25
      }
    })
  }
});
export default OrderDetailsStack;
```

Here are a screenShots it should explain what I mean

1- My Orders
[image: My Orders]

2- Order Details
[image: Order Details]

Comment: Don't really understand your question but if you ask about the blank header among those others, you can hide it by add `defaultNavigationOptions: {header: null}` to your stack navigator named `root`

Comment: Yup that's what I want, but when I set it as a "header: null" for both root and order details, it's work very well, but if the user wants to go back! That's won't happen because the header disappears:/ and if I just set a "header: null" just for a root and in the order details I will see two headers (My Orders, Order details)! @tuan.tran

Comment: Can you please rename the file names and post the code of those files with mentioning the names, now it's to confusing. It's hard to debug it.

Comment: I will just now I keep a header as hidden, can you check this Q @AshwinMothilal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065752/add-custom-creatematerialtoptabnavigator-to-component

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you are concerned about the blank header that appears on top of the screen under your first header.

That one is created by `createStackNavigator`.

A the first Stack that creates the first Header named `OrdersStack`.

Inside that you have the `root` constant (probably, as there isn't the full code) that is creating the second header.

Inside `root` you are then defining your `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` with your two screens, that's showing the topBar with the label "accepted" and "completed".

To hide that white space you have to disable your `root` header doing:

```
export const root = createStackNavigator({
  NavTabs: NavTabs,
  NavOrderDetails: NavOrderDetails
},
   {
     defaultNavigationOptions:{
       header:null
   }
});
```

UPDATE.

You have two ways to fix this and still have a backButton:

1) You can either create a parent `CustomHeader` that, using react-navigation's `withNavigation` HOC, is aware about his childrens navigation state.

2) Dinamically hide the parent header when the second one is showing. You can accomplish this using `this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetParent().setParams({showHeader:false})`
then your OrdersStack would be:

```
 const OrdersStack = createStackNavigator({
Orders: {
  screen: Orders,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    var defaultHeader={
        headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
        >
            <Icon
            name="ios-menu"
            size={40}
            style={{ margin: 10 }}
            color="#2F98AE"
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRight: <View />,
        title: "My Orders",
        headerTintColor: "#2F98AE",
        headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#2F98AE",
        // textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25
        // justifyContent: "center"
        }
    }
    if (navigation.state.params)
        return(navigation.state.params.showHeader?{defaultHeader}:null)
    else return defaultHeader

  }
}


 });
```

Comment: Yup that's what I want, but when I set it as a "header: null" for both root and order details, it's work very well, but if the user wants to go back! That's won't happen because the header disappears:/ and if I just set a "header: null" just for a root and in the order details I will see two headers (My Orders, Order details)! @Auticcat

Comment: where I can put that `this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetParent().setParams({showHeader:false})`, in which screen?

Comment: For example, inside orderDetails's componentDidMount

Comment: Just noticed that there are 3 headers, can you show me your navigation structure better?

Comment: Hey @Auticcat, I hope you fine, I've faced something like this issue can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776851/how-to-use-creatematerialtoptabnavigator-as-a-component) question, please?