# How to use createMaterialTopTabNavigator as a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Hey I have a search screen *"search for songs/artists"* So after sending the request i want to appear a "Top Tabs", So I add a Top tab `"createMaterialTopTabNavigator"` inside separate files and then import it as a component to use it inside Search Screen like this  `<SearchTabs />` But i got an error

> Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this
>   navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app
>   container directly. More info:
>   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

lib

```
"react-navigation": "^4.1.0",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
```

Top Tabs Code

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import resultArtists from './resultArtists';
import resultSongs from './resultSongs';

const SearchTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Songs: {
      screen: resultSongs,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Songs',
      },
    },
    Artists: {
      screen: resultArtists,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Artists',
      },
    },
  },
);
export default SearchTabNavigator;
```

then i import it in createStackNavigator 'Root.js Navigation file' like this

```
 SearchTabs: {
    screen: SearchTabNavigator,
  },
```

here's Search Code "That contains input then i want to appear the top tabs"

```
class Search extends PureComponent {


 render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.searchHeader}>
          <Input
            onChangeText={text => this.search(text)}
            value={this.state.searchText}
            onSubmitEditing={this.onSearch}
            returnKeyType="search"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            style={styles.searchInput}
          />
        </View>

        <SearchTabNavigator />

     </Container>

      )
 }

}

export default Search;
```

The final result should be something like this

[image: s]

### What I tried

I add new `createAppContainer` to wrap the Top tabs like this in 'Top Tabs file'

```
export const Tabs = createAppContainer(SearchTabNavigator);
```

And it's working fine.

but i think it's the wrong way, to add two AppContainer in the same app :\

And when i want to navigate from any item "songs" to Player screen 'it's in Different AppContainer' it's not working!.

Comment: @Auticcat here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anastely/f54bf0942535998297dccb6a3d7e6562)

Comment: So you want to achieve an input at the top that then has a TopBar still under the input?

Comment: @Auticcat  Yeah as you see in screenshot the input at the top and when i send the request i want to appear the Tob Tabs

Comment: The easiest way out of this is to not use a `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` to render the different tabs, but to use a different component to render the tabs, as you have full control over it. 
The part that involves react-navigation is pretty "hacky", and I'm not sure it's achievable or maintainable in the long run.

Comment: @Auticcat Hmm, so what should I do exactly if I not use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` to achieve something like it 

Comment: To change it something like https://github.com/valdio/react-native-scrollable-tabview could be a good replacement instead of the `react-navigation`'s one. You keep the code as-is and render this component instead of your current SearchTabNavigator

Comment: @Auticcat I will check it, thank you man, stay safe ✌

Comment: Let me know if you need further help to implement it, good luck!